# Ruby on Rails - want to create table with auto generated timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a migration file.

I have made **timestamps** fields **auto-generated**.

```
class CreateCustomerOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :customer_orders do |t|
      t.bigint :order_id
      t.string :customer_email

      t.timestamps, default: -> { 'NOW()' } 
    end
  end
end
```

This is error stack traces.

```
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /work/halfhelix/rewardbee/heroku-rewardbee-migration-app/db/migrate/primary/20200119193709_create_customer_orders.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '='
      t.timestamps, default: -> { 'NOW()' } 
                    ^~~~~~~~
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/zeitwerk-2.2.1/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1010:in `load_migration'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1006:in `migration'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1001:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1369:in `use_transaction?'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1361:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1310:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1269:in `run_without_lock'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1221:in `block in run'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1382:in `with_advisory_lock'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1221:in `run'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1075:in `run'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:155:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

I am not sure why I am getting this issue.
Anyone had this issue before?

Comment: Aren't auto generated timestamps the default behavior? Also, if you want help solving your syntax error you should show the stack trace and the whole file it's coming from

Comment: @maxpleaner, updated migration file.

Comment: What about the stack trace? What file and line is that error coming from?  I can't see any error with your code

Comment: @maxpleaner, added error stack traces. Thank you!

Comment: try t.timestamps,  :default => DateTime.now

Comment: and you miss ":" before default

Comment: Oh ok yeah i see the issue now. `t.timestamps` is a method call. Ben's answer solves it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
t.timestamps
```

is a shortcut to add two fields `created_at` and `updated_at`.  Both of these are automatically populated by rails.

I'm pretty sure you can't add a default to this line and I don't think you need to.  Just remove the `, default: -> { 'NOW()' }` and everything should work how you want it to.